# ASP.NET and Source Code Appearing

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an older ASP.NET web-application using framework 2.0 based on Dot Net Nuke.  The web-application used to compile and run but recently it compiles fine but instead of the application running in the browser, source code appears.  What could be causing this type of behavior?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about white-yellow error page with error line and the stack trace?

Comment: No.  It's the actual asp.net code markup. It's returning the code behind in visible text.  I cannot get the web-application to render with text boxes and such to appear--just the code for the text boxes appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like IIS is treating your .aspx files as static content.

Open IIS admin and make sure the .aspx extensions are mapped to PageHandlerFactory.  Make sure the pages exist in an application (and not just a virtual directory).  Easiest thing to do is open up IIS in a known good environment and compare the setup.

Also, make sure you have run [aspnet_regiis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx) with the appropriate .NET version.

Comment: aspnet_regiis isn't the thing to use on newer Windows releases, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules#installing-iis-and-aspnet-modules